# SQL statement: How to retrieve and display each user and the many items they purchase

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve and display 3 customers per page and also display all the items they have purchased.
Currently, my sql statment below can retrieve 3 rows of result but are the same customer if they purchase 2 or more items. I know it is possible to get what I want with multiple sql queries but is it possible to do it in one query? Please suggest if you have an idea on how people usually does it. Thanks!

```
SELECT *
FROM customers, item
WHERE customers.customer_id = customers_item.customer_id
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Database Table: Customers
- customer_id
- customer_name

Database Table: Item
- item_id
- item_name

Database Table: Customers_item
- customer_id
- item_id

Comment: Your query is about items. It merely includes customer info. Thus the multiples.

Comment: What you want? give me clarity. You are getting three rows means you are using Limit

Comment: @geomagas Yes, it display every customer but involves multiple items that they bought. Is the only way to use 2 queries, query the customer info first then query for the items they bought before displaying?

Comment: No, you could use your query. Your application could distinguish the customers while printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't perform the syntax check, but the solution can be like the following:

```
select c.*, i.*
from (select * from Customers limit 0, 3) c
join Customer_item ci on c.customer_id = ci.customer_id
join item i on ci.item_id = i.item_id
order by c.customer_name, i.item_name
```

The inner query will return the needed customers, and all the rest will join all items of the selected customers.

Hope that this will help You

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
select * from item where customer_id in (select customers_id from customers)
```

Answer (score 0):

provide a sample output you are trying to obtain.

```
select c.*, i.* from Customer c
join
Customer_item ci
on c.customer_id = ci.customer_id
join
item i
on ci.item_id = i.item_id
```

the code above gives all customers and all items bought by them.